# windows cmd works via WinExec but not via popen

Tags: c++, cmd, popen

Why does the following code work via WinExec(), but not via popen()? It should do the same, right?

```
std::string command = "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \" cd /D \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && xcopy /I .\\data\\*.* .\\build\\ \"";

WinExec(command.c_str(), SW_HIDE); //working

FILE *pipe = popen(command.c_str(), "r"); //NOT working
```

After some testing I'm even more confused, because some commands like mkdir work but not with xcopy:

1:

```
// not working
popen("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \" cd \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && xcopy .\\data\\*.* .\\build\\ \"", "r");
```

2:

```
// working
popen("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \" cd \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && mkdir test2 \"", "r");
```

3:

```
// not working 
popen("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \" cd \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && xcopy \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\\data\\*.*\" \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\\build\\\" \"", "r");
```

4:

```
// working 
popen("C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c \" xcopy \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\\data\\*.*\" \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\\build\\\" \"", "r");
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-170) (emphasis mine):

> The `_popen` function creates a pipe. It then asynchronously executes **a spawned copy of the command processor**, and uses command as the command line.

So I think you should omit the `cmd /c` part and that should make it easier to get it to work.

Comment: with `std::string command = "cd /D \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && xcopy /I .\\data\\*.* .\\build\\";` neither works anymore. The cmd /c "command" ensures that both commands are executed one after the other in a terminal and that works. In example 3 you can see that the directory is changed with cd and a folder is then created in this directory with mkdir. That also works with popen(). My question is why then xcopy doesn't work, because in both cases (with mkdir and with xcopy) they are relative directories.

Comment: OK.  @JohannesK71083 What steps have you taken to try to debug this?  `mkdir` is a built-in command BTW, that may be relevant here.

Comment: I found a solution. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If I do the following it works:

`std::string command = "start cmd /c \" cd /D \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && xcopy /I /E /C /Y .\\data\\*.* .\\build\\ \"";`

or

`std::string command = "cmd /c \" cd /D \"C:\\Users\\Johannes\\Desktop\\test\" && start xcopy /I /E /C /Y .\\data\\*.* .\\build\\ \"";`.

From now on I will always do `start cmd /c ""`, then it will always work in any case.

But one question remains. Why does it work like this and not otherwise?